# MITLM smoothing

Tags: linux, memory, smoothing

I have problem with smoothing large files of 3-grams counts.
I use :estimate-ngram -order 3 -counts allgrams -smoothing FixModKN -wl allgrams.FixModKN.lm command and i get this error:

```
Saving LM to train.corpus.lm...
estimate-ngram: src/NgramModel.cpp:422: void NgramModel::SaveLM(const 
std::vector<DenseVector<double>, std::allocator<DenseVector<double> > >&, const 
std::vector<DenseVector<double>, std::allocator<DenseVector<double> > >&, ZFile&) 
const: Assertion `(size_t)(ptr - lineBuffer.data()) < lineBuffer.size()' failed.
```

Before I tried on 2-grams with 4,7GB files and it works fine. 3-grams file is 20GB big.

My operating system is GNU/Linux x86_64 with 96GB RAM